# Resize image from Ajax table

Tags: jquery

How can I resize the image inside the Ajax table?

After running the codes , I can only get image with different size.
How can I resize them to the same size.

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


 var Ref = firebase.database().ref().child("cases");
 Ref.on("child_added", snap => {
 var name = snap.child("name").val();
 var region = snap.child("gender").val();
 var form = snap.child("tutorsubject").val();
 var photo = snap.child("photoURL").val();

 var image = "<img src='" + photo + "' /img>";



 $("#table_body").appendTo("<tr><td>" + image + "</td><td>" + 
 name +      "    </td><td>" + region + "</td><td>" + form +"
 </td><td><button>按此申請</td></tr>");




});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide "height" & "width" attribute to the image tag.

```
<img src="img-path.jpg" alt="my image" width="200" height="300">
```

If you are using Bootstrap in your application, you can use CSS Class "img-responsive". Read more details [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)

```
<img src="img-path.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: <img src="img-path.jpg" alt="my image" width="200" height="300"> is not working

Comment: not working means, is it not changing the height & width of the image inside the <td> element. Could you please explain in detail.